# How should i read more number of messages from dead letter using .net core c#?

Tags: azure, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, azureservicebus

I have below code which works fine but when function got trigger it only read one message at a time.

> to get more than 1 message i have given `count 10` into `ReceiveAsync(10)` , but 
>   still getting only one message.

```
public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *")]TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    try
    {

        var deadQueuePath = EntityNameHelper.FormatDeadLetterPath("demo/subscriptions/demo");

        MessageReceiver deadletterReceiver = new MessageReceiver(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"), deadQueuePath, ReceiveMode.PeekLock,RetryPolicy.Default);
        MessageSender sender = new MessageSender(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConnectionStringSettingName"), "demo",RetryPolicy.Default);

        var deadLetter = await deadletterReceiver.ReceiveAsync(10);
        if (deadLetter != null)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"got new message");

            Message newMessage = new Message(deadLetter.Body)
            {
                ContentType = deadLetter.ContentType,
                CorrelationId = deadLetter.CorrelationId                          
            };

            //Send the message to the Active Queue
            await sender.SendAsync(newMessage);
            await deadletterReceiver.CompleteAsync(item.SystemProperties.LockToken); //Unlock the message and remove it from the DLQ

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Exception: {ex}");
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO, it depends on how long you waste on handling the message. If you try `ReceiveAsync(10)`, you will need to loop through received mesages. In general, you may consider using async method to process. Try to refer [Best Practices for performance improvements using Service Bus Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-performance-improvements#scenarios)

Comment: after using `ReceiveAsync(10),` also i'm getting only 1 message :(

Answer (score 1):

**ReceiveAsync(10)** - This method is used for setting the sequence number of the message to receive and not the count. Look at the details on [ReceiveAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver.receiveasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_MessageReceiver_ReceiveAsync_System_Int64_) here

In order to fetch multiple messages, you need to set **[Prefetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.queueclient.prefetchcount?view=azure-dotnet)** property to the receiver.

Make use of the below constructor to initialize your MessageReceiver Class:

```
public MessageReceiver (Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ServiceBusConnection serviceBusConnection, string entityPath, Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ReceiveMode receiveMode = Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.ReceiveMode.PeekLock, Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus.RetryPolicy retryPolicy = null, int prefetchCount = 0);
```